# Sending video and audio stream to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to develop a system where there are two clients that can video chat to each other from their browsers over a server. First client sends its video stream to the server and the server sends it to the second client. Also, server saves client's stream as a video file.

I used this WebRTC example: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/master/src/content/getusermedia/source/js/main.js

Server side;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('C:/source/'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('C:/source/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('user connected.');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected.');
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        ?
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client side;

```
var socket = io();

while(streaming) {
   socket.emit(?);
}
```

I can't understand that from which source I should emit the video + audio stream of the client to the server. If I successfully upload the stream, I will be able to handle it on server side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need a server that is capable of processing WebRTC media.

I suggest looking into [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/), [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/), [Jitsi Videobridge](https://jitsi.org/), [FreeSWITCH](https://freeswitch.org/) and [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) as alternatives.

This will require a lot more effort from your end, as all will necessitate learning more about them, WebRTC and real-time media processing.

If you need this working yesterday and want to put your efforts and focus elsewhere, you should check out some of the vendors listed in this [report about WebRTC PaaS](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-paas-report/).

Comment: Are you suggesting me to not to do it myself and use a project that has already done it?

Comment: If you need it to be working yesterday, I believe you want to use something that is already done.If you have the time and want to do it, I can say that it is a wonderful long journey to learn so many protocols and implement them.

Comment: Definitely use something that is out there already - unless what you are trying to do is have a learning experience or make that a core differentiator (which you probably don't)